# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in App_Web_1wvcoe1q.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, stack-overflow

I have an ASP.Net MVC application. Recently it worked correctly and now when I run it and enter login credentials it hangs long time and says

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in App_Web_1wvcoe1q.dll

I've tried a lot by clearing all ASP.Net temporally files and Visual studio temporally files.

But still have the same issue. I guess nothing wrong with my code in the login page. This happened suddenly.

This is the login method

```
 [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult LogIn(string loginId, string password, string plantCode, string returnUrl)
        {
            bool valid = false;

            if (loginId.IsEmpty())
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Login id cannot be empty";
            }
            else if (password.IsEmpty())
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be empty";
            }
            else if (plantCode.IsEmpty())
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Plant code cannot be empty";
            }
            else
            {
                //Domain
                using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
                {
                    valid = context.ValidateCredentials(loginId, password);
                }
                //Domain

                //Cloud
                //valid = true;
                //Cloud

                var user = ValidateUserPlant(loginId, plantCode);
                if (valid && user != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginId, true);
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.Password] = password;
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.LoginId] = loginId;
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.PlantId] = user.PlantId;
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.UserId] = user.Id;
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.Email] = user.Email;
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.UserName] = user.Name;
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.UserData] = user;
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.UserName] = user.Name;
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.DepartmentId] = user.DepartmentId;
                    Session[ConstantVariables.SessionVariables.ProductionSectionId] = user.ProductionSectionId;
                    return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Home" }) + returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Invalid User Name or Password";
                }
            }

            return View("Index");
        }
```

And the call stack location

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue was with visual studio 2012.

Once I installed the **Visual Studio 2012 Update 5** the issue resolved.